# Groovy way to find valid end of a range

Tags: groovy

Imagine I have a big list I want to split up in to smaller chunks for processing:

```
def chunkSize = 10
def listSize = aBigList.size()
for(def i = 0; i < listSize; i += chunkSize) {
    def startOfRange = i
    def endOfRange = (listSize - 1) < (i + increment - 1) ? (listSize - 1) : (i + increment - 1) // There has got to be a better way!
    def chunk = aBigList[startOfRange..endOfRange]
    // do something with chunk
}
```

The code for getting the `endOfRange` variable is ugly and non-groovy, but is required in order to prevent an `Index Out of Bounds` exception.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you use [collate](http://blog.bloidonia.com/post/18073244930/whats-new-in-groovy-1-8-6-the-collate-method)?

```
def chunks = aBigList.collate( chunkSize )
```

If not, fixing your code gives you something like:

```
def chunkSize = 10
def listSize = aBigList.size()
for( i = 0; i < listSize; i += chunkSize ) {
    def endOfRange = i + chunkSize - 1 >= aBigList.size() ? -1 : i + chunkSize - 1
    def chunk = aBigList[ i..endOfRange ]
    // do something with chunk
}
```

But collate is probably the way to go so long as `aBigList` isn't truly enormous ;-)